# Create xml file without prologue with python dom minidom

Tags: python, xml, dom, minidom

I create a xml file with the library dom minidom of Python. However i want create my xml file without the prolog `<?xml version="1.0"?>`. I use `doc.writexml()` Please can you give me few leads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this directly. But there are two hacky ways to do it.

First, it's not too hard to strip it out. For example:

```
xml = x.toxml()
with open('foo.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(xml.partition('>')[2])
```

Or, if you don't want to generate the whole string in memory, you can write a file wrapper that swallows the prolog:

```
class SkipFirstWriter(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.firstline = True
    def write(self, buf):
        if self.firstline:
            if '>' in buf:
                self.f.write(buf.partition('>')[2])
                self.firstline = False
        else:
            self.f.write(buf)
with open('foo.xml', 'w') as f:
    skipper = SkipFirstWriter(f)
    x.writexml(skipper)
```

Obviously swallowing "everything up to the first `>`" is a bit of a hacky way to detect the XML prolog… but it works. In real-life code, I'd probably add a comment explaining that this works, and why, but use it.

Alternatively, you could rely on the fact that the document-without-prolog is the first child of the document, and do this:

```
with open('foo.xml', 'w') as f:
    x.firstChild.writexml(f)
```